# How to get profile tab from faceit match?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to get url from faceit match
For example [faceit match](https://www.faceit.com/en/csgo/room/1-b0384d14-9625-49ca-8979-fa7a816d8c3c)

I need to get this tab [tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPrNN.png)

But when I am trying to get by BS4, it doesn`t show any elements
BECAUSE It's being loaded dynamically. How to make python get this 10 tabs, then I will just extract steam urls. Help me please
[i want to get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbQdR.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] and show us your [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As page is loading dynamically, you need to inspect the network tab to see where the data comes from. I'm not sure what sort of data you are after, but you can, for example, do this (after inspecting Network tab and determine which call is pulling your relevant data):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://api.faceit.com/match/v2/match/1-b0384d14-9625-49ca-8979-fa7a816d8c3c') ## one of the network calls, visible in Network tab, Dev tools

dfs = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['payload']['voting']['map']['entities'])
dfs
```

This will print out:

```
class_name  game_map_id guid    image_lg    image_sm    name
0   de_dust2    de_dust2    de_dust2    https://assets.faceit-cdn.net/third_party/game...   https://assets.faceit-cdn.net/third_party/game...   Dust2
1   de_mirage   de_mirage   de_mirage   https://assets.faceit-cdn.net/third_party/game...   https://assets.faceit-cdn.net/third_party/game...   Mirage
2   de_nuke de_nuke de_nuke https://assets.faceit-cdn.net/third_party/game...   https://assets.faceit-cdn.net/third_party/game...   Nuke
3   de_overpass de_overpass de_overpass https://assets.faceit-cdn.net/third_party/game...   https://assets.faceit-cdn.net/third_party/game...   Overpass
4   de_train    de_train    de_train    https://assets.faceit-cdn.net/third_party/game...   https://assets.faceit-cdn.net/third_party/game...   Train
5   de_inferno  de_inferno  de_inferno  https://assets.faceit-cdn.net/third_party/game...   https://assets.faceit-cdn.net/third_party/game...   Inferno
6   de_vertigo  de_vertigo  de_vertigo  https://assets.faceit-cdn.net/third_party/game...   https://assets.faceit-cdn.net/third_party/game...   Vertigo
7   de_ancient  de_ancient  de_ancient  https://assets.faceit-cdn.net/third_party/game...   https://assets.faceit-cdn.net/third_party/game...   Ancient
```

You can further inspect the json response and see which data is relevant to you.

Comment: In my screen, you can see the clickable tab, how can I access it?

Comment: Inspect the json response you received from the url above. If the data is not there, inspect the other urls from Network tab.